# check for dependencies on other servers in SQL server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have an old server running SQL Server 2000.

I need to perform some maintenance on the server and one step is to check for dependencies on other servers.

The SQL Server 2000 machine has database A, while database B is running on a different server.  DB A has stored procedures that will modify some table fields on DB B and vice-versa.  I want to know what cross DB/Server references there are, what should I do?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "its dependencies on other servers" and how `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats` is related to that?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Let me give more details, my old DB has stored procedures that referred to other DB tables on other servers, and other servers also has stored procedures or jobs that referred to table fields of my old DB. For example, database A execute stored proc SP1, it inserts a row to table T1 in database B, but A and B are on different servers. how am I able to know those the cross DB and cross server references?

Comment: @mustaccio, you're right, sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats is not related to that, I removed it from the question.

Answer (score -1):

I'm fairly sure that there isn't a reliable way to do this. I remember being very surprised when I dropped and recreated a table in SQL Server 2000 and lost all the dependencies to the stored procedures that refer to it.

You can try looking at sysremotelogins and sysservers, but I doubt that will cover the full list.